# Numpy array bool operation slow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I started profiling my application and I tested to following code:

```
a = np.random.random((100000,))
        
def get_first_index(value, arr):
   firstIndex = np.argmax(arr > value)
   if firstIndex <= 0:
      raise Exception('No index found')
   return firstIndex

for i in range(0, 1000):
   get_first_index(0.5, a)
```

It just returns me the first index of an element bigger than the given value. On my machine it takes around 0.01s for array size 50k and 1k calls. I was wondering what causes the slow down. My first suspect was `np.argmax` but I boiled it down to the boolean comparison `arr > value`. It spends 99% of the time creating the bool comparison. Is there any faster way I am not aware of?

Test code for profiling:

```
a = np.random.random((100000,))

def test_function(a, b):
    return a < b

import cProfile, pstats

profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.enable()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    test_function(0.5, a)

profiler.disable()
stats = pstats.Stats(profiler).sort_stats('tottime')
stats.print_stats()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your approach is slow is that all elements of `arr` are compared under all circumstances, even if the first element of `arr` is greater than `value`.

While numpy does not have an API optimized for this kind of processing, [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) can be used instead, which can be easily implemented as follows.

```py
import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.random((100000,))


def get_first_index(value, arr):
    firstIndex = np.argmax(arr > value)
    if firstIndex <= 0:
        raise Exception("No index found")
    return firstIndex


@numba.njit("i8(f8,f8[:])", cache=True)
def get_first_index2(value, arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] > value:
            return i
    raise Exception("No index found")


x = 0.9999
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: get_first_index(x, a), number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: get_first_index2(x, a), number=1000))
```

```
0.01520979999999994
0.001343500000000053
```

As a side note, if `arr` is a sorted array, [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is even faster.

Comment: Your side note was gold! The array is indeed already sorted and `np.searchsorted` is working super fast. Thanks!